# Negative coefficients in the barycentric calculus

Tags: geometry, linear-algebra

The barycentric calculus of Möbius involves formal sums of expressions of the form $mP$ where $m$ is a real number and $P$ is a point, where $mP$ is to be thought of as $m$ units of mass located at $P$. This is not problematic as long as all masses are positive. But how did Möbius interpret expressions like $(1)P + (-1)Q$? Nowadays we would identify it with the vector from $Q$ to $P$. Did Möbius have any interpretation of this kind?

Comment: I just found R. E. Allardice's exposition "The Barycentric Calculus of Möbius" (https://www.cambridge.org/core/services/aop-cambridge-core/content/view/235A89804289968FD4C285175D234A86/S0013091500030923a.pdf/the-barycentric-calculus-of-mobius.pdf), according to which Möbius' said that when $a+b+\dots+n$ is zero, $aA + bB + \dots + nN$ "is at infinity". Should we interpret this in the sense of projective geometry? If so, then perhaps Möbius was doing an arcane kind of vectorial analysis.

Answer (score 2):

The Wikipedia article Barycentric coordinate system states:

> In geometry, a barycentric coordinate system is a coordinate system in which the location of a point is specified by reference to a simplex (a triangle for points in a plane, a tetrahedron for points in three-dimensional space, etc.). The barycentric coordinates of a point can be interpreted as masses placed at the vertices of the simplex, such that the point is the center of mass (or barycenter) of these masses. These masses can be zero or negative; they are all positive if and only if the point is inside the simplex.
>
> Every point has barycentric coordinates, and their sum is not zero. Two tuples of barycentric coordinates specify the same point if and only if they are proportional; that is to say, if one tuple can be obtained by multiplying the elements of the other tuple by the same non-zero number. Therefore, barycentric coordinates are either considered to be defined up to multiplication by a nonzero constant, or normalized for summing to unity.

The quote "is at infinity" does suggest projective geometry.
In fact, this can be made precise. Consider three dimensional
Euclidean space with Cartesian coordinates. Interpret the
homogeneous coordinate triple $(x: y: z)$ as referring to a two
dimensional plane point $(x/z, y/z)$ with *weight* $z$ where the
weights are additive. That is, the weight function $(x, y, z)
\mapsto z$ is linear. Note the relation $(x_1: y_1: z_1) \equiv
(x_2: y_2: z_2)$ iff $(x_1, y_1, z_1) = w(x_2, y_2, z_2)$ where
$w\ne 0$. This equivalence relation partitions the space into
equivalence classes with representatives unit weight $(x: y: 1)$
which represents the point $(x, y)$ if $z\ne 0.$

The zero weight triple $(x: y: 0)$ represents a point on the line
at infinity. One way to understand this is to consider the point
$R :=(w)P + (1-w)Q$ as $w$ varies. If $w=0$ it is the point $Q$.
If $w=1$ it is the point $P$. In the limit where $w\to\infty$ the
two weights $1-w$ and $w$ are proportional to $-1$ and $1$ while
the  point $R$ move off to infinity. Thus, $(1)P +(-1)Q$ represents
the point on the line at infinity in the *direction* of the vector
from $Q$ to $P$. There are contexts where $(1)P +(-1)Q$ represents
the vector from $Q$ to $P$ but this is not one of them.

Comment: Thanks for suggesting this interpretation. Did Möbius advance such an interpretation, or failing that, were his rules of operation compatible with it?

Comment: @JamesPropp I have not read what Möbius wrote, but he probably understood the projective interpretation. I don't understand everything that Allardice wrote but it seems to me that it agrees with my interpretation.